# Decode a string with nested encodes

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, encoding

strong textGiven a string that has been encoded n times, how can I decode the string to give me the plain unencoded string if I don't know the value of n.

To clarify:

```
Initial : /unencoded?string/

Encoded Once : %2Funencoded%3Fstring%2F

Encoded Twice: %252Funencoded%253Fstring%252F

Encoded Three Times: %25252Funencoded%25253Fstring%25252F
```

How do I get from `%25252Funencoded%25253Fstring%25252F` to `/unencoded?string/` **without knowing it's been encoded three times**?

I know I can use `HttpServerUtility.UrlDecode` or similar, but this only decodes once.

Comment: Using `HttpServerUtility.UrlDecode(HttpServerUtility.UrlDecode(...));` ?

Comment: As mentioned, I don't know how many times its been encoded and therefore don't know how many times to apply HttpServerUtility.UrlDecode

Comment: `while(encoded.indexOf("/") < 1){ encoded = HttpServerUtility.UrlDecode(encoded); }`

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure that will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

decode it until decoding doesn't change it any more.

```
string encodedString = "....";
string temp = string.Empty;
string decodedString = HttpServerUtility.UrlDecode(encodedString);
while (decodedString != temp)
{
    temp=decodedString;
    decodedString = HttpServerUtility.UrlDecode(temp);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this!!

Answer (score 2):

Updated .NET version of hometoast's answer below.

Essentially just swap `HttpServerUtility.UrlDecode` with `HttpUtility.UrlDecode`

```
string encodedString = "....";
string temp = string.Empty;
string decodedString = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(encodedString);
while (decodedString != temp)
{
    temp=decodedString;
    decodedString = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(temp);
}
```